# Why `arabxetex` does not apply the arabicfont for including macros?

Tags: fontspec, arabxetex

Why `arabxetex` does not use the `arabicfont` for macros included in like `\marginpar` and `\footnote`, it seems so weird? I think as the text appeared in the `arab` environment, all the following macros in it should use the default font for the environment. The following MWE shows the issue.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arabxetex} 
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}


\begin{arab}[utf]
سلام علیکم \footnote{سلام}
\marginpar{++سلام علیکم++}
\marginpar{++Hello++}

\end{arab}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the environment doesn't change \normalfont used by \marginpar and \footnote. You could add `\let\normalfont\arabicfont`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks, but I was expected that the package would do it by itself like the way `XePersian` package did. What is your opinion of changing the normal font by `arabxetex` in such cases? I mean, is it a bug for `arabxetex`?

Comment: @javadr No, not a bug. 
Arabxetex, consisting of 1 code file of 482 lines + "an extensive collection of TECKit [mapping] files", is designed for producing text in Arabic script by typing in transliterated text. The manual is mostly a table of these mappings.

xePersian, made up of 61 code files, is designed for producing various documents in Arabic script. The .sty file is >1500 lines, and there is one file with almost a thousand lines of localisation of commands like `\eqcommand{درحاشیه‌عادی}{normalmarginpar}`.

Both are packages, contents are different.

Comment: @javadr Arabxetex is an "ArabTeX-like interface for XeLaTeX", so how you set things up depends on what you want to do with it. The manual gives an example of how to set up a preamble to do critical editions, and then adds: "Of course if the edition is typed directly in UTF-8 encoding, the use of ArabXETEX is by no means compulsory." (p10, fn16). In any case, "Since most of the ‘real work’ – namely parsing and converting ArabTEX input to Unicode – is done at the level of TECkit mappings, ArabXETEX is really performant." (from the abstract)